# Как с помощью gulp сохранить в шаблонный html файл время последнего обновления?

Tags: node.js, шаблоны, gulp

Есть шаблонный html файл, и нужно при изменении проекта,записать время обновления сайта. Gulp следит за изменениями.
Сам шаблонный файл может тоже корректироваться в дальнейшем и хотелось бы в нём иметь место **[[Сюда подставить время]]** и что б gulp при изменении проекта брал файл и в это место вставлял дату и время и выдавал на основе шаблона готовый html файл.
Как такое сделать?

Comment: В простейшем случае - использовать поиск/замену, например [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace). Либо использовать какой-то шаблонизатор/препроцессор, например [gulp-preprocess](https://github.com/jas/gulp-preprocess).

Answer (score 1):

Как уже рекомендовали в [комментариях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/677812/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-gulp-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-html-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#comment991454_677812) (самое простое и эффективное решение), используйте [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace):

Ставим:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-replace
```

Используем:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');

gulp.task('build', function() {
    var time = new Date().toTimeString();
    gulp.src('src/index.html')
        .pipe(replace('[[Сюда подставить время]]', time))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});

gulp.watch('src/**/*.*', ['build']);

gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```